# use facebook app with different websites

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, wordpress

i know that its not possible to register more than one website url to same facebook app, but there is a solution i think, this solution is to make some sort of a login service in a fixed url and login through this url.

in wordpress, there are some plugins works with your facebook ( posting, uploading, etc..) works with thier own facebook app, you don't have to make your app, i noticed the when i am logging in, it redirects me to thier website first then to facebook and then return to me, this solution that i am talking about .... one of these plugins called wordbooker

so i made an app and gave my website url to it, and made a .php page in my website (which will be the login service) i sends to it the url that i want to login to facebook from it, then this .php page go to facebook and logged in and and returns to my page then to the requested page.

i sends all parameters returned from facebook login (state and code) to the requested website but it does not logged in, i don't know why? i think i misunderstabding something ...

so can you help please ...

Comment: Here is a complete tutorial http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/php-sdk-3-0-graph-api-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/ it may help you

Comment: that´s just a simple tutorial for facebook, but it does not mention different websites...

Comment: thanks @TariqAziz but i think it don't solve my problem, i need to make the center step (login from one website and sends the paramters to requested websites.

Answer (score 0):

You can only define one website in the app, the only way is to use subfolders or subdomains.

Btw, it is also against the facebook rules, facebook apps must be used for only one site/purpose.

Comment: yes i agree with you, but this way i am sure that it worksm but how ??

Comment: well, of course you are not logged in on that other website, the session is only valid for the specific website (the first one). facebook knows what they are doing ;)

Comment: okay, i gave you example, in wordpress, there are some plugins works with your facebook ( posting, uploading, etc..) works with thier own facebook app, you don't have to make your app, i noticed the when i am logging in, it redirects me to thier website first then to facebook and then return to me, this solution that i am talking about .... one of these plugins called wordbooker

Comment: i have already used wordbooker, don´t you need your own app for it to work? i could be wrong though, did not use it very long. even if it uses its own app, that´s different because you actually login to the wordbooker site and it just uses the app for publishing...

Comment: yes, that is what i am talking about, do you have any idea how they implemented this stuff? and thanks for help

Comment: well, you can just download their sourcecode, it´s public anyway :)

Comment: ohh sorry, i mean to know how the code they used on thier server to handle logging and redirecting not the code about publishing :)

Comment: i don´t think it matters, because you are not logged in on your own domain anyway. isn´t that what you needed? to be logged in on the other/second domain`?

Comment: yes i want to be logged in on any website through my website (which used my facebook app)

Comment: exactly. that´s not what wordbooker does, and afaik it is not possible.

Comment: kindly may you explain how i could implement what you talking about? i am missed the point

Comment: I guess you can do what you want by posting data from the domain associated with the application to the Facebook, and when you need to display the data on any other site you can either post the data the website requires or you can have a web page included in an iFrame, which displays data you require.